# XML Parsing with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, html-agility-pack, azure-worker-roles

I'm parsing xml with HtmlAgilityPack on WebService worker role, but there is something wrong. When I select childnode "link" get empty char. 
the xml like :

```
<link>
http://www.webtekno.com/google/google-ve-razer-dan-oyun-konsolu.html
</link>
```

my code for get link from rss is:

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodeList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//item");
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string newsUri = node.ChildNodes["link"].InnerText;
}
```

I think gets empty char cause link node includes new line and after link. How can I get link in the  node?

Comment: Why? Can't you use proper XML API (like `XDocument`)?

Comment: I try it but problem is still exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put that line before loading HtmlDocument

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["link"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
```

That is all.

By default, its value is `HtmlElementFlag.Empty` and treated like `meta` and `img` tags...